React Native Navigation Authenticated Screens
export default function App() {
  async function getStore(){
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('my-auth');
      if (value !== null) {
        console.log('he',value)
      return true
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // error reading value
    }
  
  }
 const token=getStore();
  return (
  
<Provider store={store}>
<MenuProvider>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Screen1' screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
  }} >
{token ?
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen1"  options={{  animation:'slide_from_right' }} component={Screen1}  />
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen2"  options={{  animation:'slide_from_right' }} component={Screen2}  />
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen3"  options={{  animation:'slide_from_right' }} component={Screen3}  />
:
      <Stack.Screen name="Login"  options={{  animation:'slide_from_right' }} component={Screen1}  />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register"  options={{  animation:'slide_from_right' }} component={Screen2}  />
}


      </Stack.Navigator>    
    </NavigationContainer><StatusBar hidden/>
    </MenuProvider></Provider>
  );
} 

I need to access authenticated screens when there exists a token in AsyncStorage and access the LOGIN and SIGNUP screens otherwise. When I implement it like this as given in the docs, the getStore() function doesn't update after logging in from second stack successfully and thus doesn't change the stack. In the docs it is given that it changes the screens automatically, but it is not doing so. (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) How do I make this work in App.js, how to ensure that the stack changes with the below code on login and logout after token is removed, any insight would be helpful, Thanks!

Although you are reading the token, React however hasn't any clue about it. [1]
This is because you are storing token in a normal variable
const token = getStore();

To make React aware of it, what you have to do is store the token in a state, and update this state on your getStore() function.
const [token, setToken] = useState('');

async function getStore() {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('my-auth');
      if (value !== null) {
        console.log('he',value);
        setToken(value); // set the token if its available
        return true
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // error reading value
    }
  
  }

Then you can initialise the token on mount with useEffect.
...

useEffect(() => {
  getStore();
}, []);

...

With these changes React will be aware of the tokens value and render accordingly.
P.S you might get some linter error to wrap the getStore function with a useCallback. Do all those accordingly.
References:
1: https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory#when-a-regular-variable-isnt-enough

this will not help with refreshing screen after login, it's better to use useContext for this or other global state managers

He just has to update the token promptly using setToken. How he does that is upto him. Providers / Context or other global state managers are one of the many available options.
